# How to run SQL query on firebase

Tags: android, sql, firebase

How to run SQL query that shows `Customers` `Problem` by `Devices` on Android Studio.

[Image](https://ibb.co/cpPEgc)

I need the next query:

```
select *
from customer, device, problem
where (customer.id=device.id)AND(customer.id=problem.id)
```

Comment: Firebase is not SQL. So you don't run a SQL query against it. You should take a Firebase tutorial first.

Comment: To learn more about how to map common SQL queries to Firebase, watch [Firebase for SQL developers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLl-K7zZEsYLlP-k-RKFa7RyNPa9_wCH2s). Firebase Database queries can only order/filter on a single property. In many cases it is possible to combine the values you want to filter on into a single (synthetic) property. For an example of this and other approaches, see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26700924/query-based-on-multiple-where-clauses-in-firebase

Comment: thank you very much but in the videos, he shows how to that in code? Because this in my project at Android studio?